# Assign a CSS class to a selected element WebComponent

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, lit-element

I'm working on a school project based on WebComponents where we have to draw a calendar (I just hardcoded it) and we have to pass a value (the day of the month) on the HTML tag, just like this:

```html
<calendar-sheet day=1></calendar-sheet>
```

I want to apply a specific CSS class (.active) to the same day that is passed. For example, if I write day=10, I want to apply that class to the tenth day of the month.
I have added a specific ID for every day in order to identify the days, like this:

```html
<li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
<li id="3">3</li>
<li id="4">4</li>
<li id="5">5</li>
```

I tried to do the following, but I am stuck here:

```js
selectDay(){
   this.renderRoot.getElementById(this.day).classList.add('active')
}
```

Comment: @isherwood yes, I am using WebComponents (LitElements), so Im working on a component, not in a whole web, so document.getElement doesnt work

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman since HTML5 it is allowed to start IDs with a number, but not on CSS

Comment: Are you able to debug your `selectDay` func?
If so, check what is the value of `this.day` and `this.renderRoot.getElementById(this.day)`?
I guess finding out this, will help you solve the problem.

Comment: BTW, @Danny'365CSI'Engelman is right, it's not a good practice anyway to name your ids and classes with numbers only. try something like `day-1`, `day-2`, etc.

Comment: If you're still seeking an answer for this issue, we need to see a bit more code. I'm not very experienced in [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) but it would be helpful to know when `selectDay` is being called, for instance. It needs to be enough code that we can reproduce the problem, at minimum.